# connecting HDMI monitor to DVI/USB port

Tags: display, cable, external-display, displayport

I am going to buy new computer with high specs, but it doesn't have hdmi port.
It will have instead:   4xUSB 2.0 ir 2xUSB 3.1, PS/2, RJ-45; 1xUSB 2.0, 1xUSB 3.0; VGA, DVI.

My monitor has DVI and HDMI.

What should i do to maximize resolution? Use adapters HDMI to usb3.0/DVI, or just connect DVI cable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the resolution of your monitor?

Comment: Full HD 1920x1080 75hz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Single-link DVI will run 1920x1080 but will limit you to 60 Hz.

If both your monitor and your computer support dual-link DVI (this should be in the spec sheets) then you can run 1920x1080 at 75 Hz.

A DVI to HDMI adapter won't help a bit.

A USB 3 video interface with HDMI out should let you run 1920x1080 @75 Hz.

However, note that USB video adapters cannot rival the performance of dedicated graphic cards, or even of "integrated graphics". They are not for high performance graphics like gaming. For an additional monitor for e.g. spreadsheets, powerpoint, word documents, even photo editing, they're fine.